# How to compose libraries with Gnu make?

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, static-libraries

I'm trying to create a library, called A.a, that provides a class A, which depends on the classes B and C, all in their respective files (`.cpp` and `.hpp`). I usually compiled all my code manually, but as the number of files increased, I wanted to use a makefile. Basically, what I would do was:

```
g++ -c A.cpp
g++ -c B.cpp
g++ -c C.cpp
ar rvs A.a *.o
```

How can I construct a makefile that does this? Can makefiles even call `ar`?

This is what I tried:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
objects=C.o B.o

all : A.o $(objects) #Creates the library called A.a.
:ar rvs A.a A.o $(objects)

A.o : $(objects) A.hpp A.cpp
:$(CC) $(CFLAGS) A.cpp

B.o : B.hpp B.cpp
:$(CC) $(CFLAGS) B.cpp

C.o : C.hpp C.cpp
:$(CC) $(CFLAGS) C.cpp
```

But it seems that my `ar rvs A.a A.o $(objects)` instruction isn't even executing. This makefile produces all the correct `.o` files, but doesn't archive them.

Comment: First off, the lines containing commands to build a target must be prefixed with a tab character. Secondly, I'm not sure what the ':' prefix on the commands is supposed to do - I'm aware of the '@' and '-' prefixes, but I've never seen a ':' there before. Other than that, it looks like it should work...

Comment: ':' Can be used insted of a tab, as stated on the official Gnu make website. Also, you can use a target : dependencies ; recepy.

Comment: Interesting... The info file I consulted didn't contain that little fact (at least not in the obvious locations). There's my "learn something new" for today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so my syntax was correct after all, or, at least, a big portion of it was. I went with a wrong premise that `:`'s could replace tabs, which is, apparently, not correct after all.

So, this is the code that does what I want:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
objects=B.o C.o

all : A.a

A.o : $(objects) A.hpp A.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) A.cpp

B.o : B.hpp B.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) B.cpp

C.o : C.hpp C.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) C.cpp

A.a : A.o $(objects)
    ar rvs A.a A.o $(objects)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use rules and patterns to make it more generic:

```
SRC_DIR = .
CPPFLAGS += -g
INCLUDES = -I.

# variant 1
SRCS ?= $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name '*.cpp' | sed "s/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\///")
# variant 2
SRCS = A.cpp B.cpp

%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $^

all : A.a

A.a : $(SRCS:.cpp=.o) 
    $(AR) rsv $@ $^
```